# How to find out the value of the surface plotted by plot_surface in a given point?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a set of points `(x_i, y_i)` and values `F(x_i, y_i)` for every point, all points are the nodes of a rectangular grid.

Using this data I plot surface `F(x, y)` by `plot_surface` function and find line curves `F(x, y) = const` of the resulting surface by `contour` function.

What I need is to know the value of the surface `F(x, y)` in a point `(x, y)` not belonged to the initial grid.

1. Is there any method that can help me?
2. If there is not, how `matplotlib.pyplot.contour` works, how does it
   get contours?

If it interpolate surface, I can interpolate it by the same way myself and find target value.

Comment: it does interpolate.  I would suggest looking at the code directly.